# Allow access to Postgresql from any computer

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

After researching GUI's for Postgresql I found the pgadmin 4 desktop client to be a valid choice.

I use an Ubuntu 16.04 server (droplet on Digital Ocean) and iptables firewall.

How do I allow access from remote computers? My computers with pgadmin installed have dynamic ip's.

Comment: are you running this in the cloud, or on your local network? How much control of your local network do you have?

Comment: This is in the cloud, on an Digital Ocean droplet. Root access. The pgadmin 4 client is only installed on my Windows local computers.

Comment: from a firewall perspective, open up port 5432. 
As to how to reference it from a gui (I use postico) the main details you need are a host and a login. DO should give you a consistent way to reference your machine, be that an IP address or like on AWS will give you a host like ec2.amazon-west-2-sdfasdf-324345asdf.aws.com. use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to connect to my cloud hosted Postgresql database from remote desktop computers with a client such as pgadmin.

To achieve this I opened up port 5432 in iptables by the following commands:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT 
service iptables save 
service iptables restart
```

I allowed access from any location in Postgresql like so:

```
nano /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
```

Edit listen_address like so:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

save and close nano editor and execute the postgresql restart command

```
service postgresql restart
```

Answer (score 10):

Are you wanting to administer Postgresql from the local network or are you wanting to allow other users in the wide world to connect to your Postgresql server?

To allow yourself access to the server to administer it on the same subnet is very easy.    To allow users in the wide world to access your server is unwise.

To allow remote access: 
You need to edit the pg_HBA.conf file.  By default it only allows a user local to the server to connect to the database.   This is a setup security thing.

The following snippet is from my own Postgresql server:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

This says that only allow the hosts that match 127.0.0.1/32 to access my server.

If you wish to allow all computers in your subnet to access your Postgresql server you may do something like the following:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             192.168.0.1/24            md5
```

The above example will get you going but it would be wise to go and briefly read the postgresql documentation for the pg_hba.conf file.

If you were particularly reckless and irrisponsible and enjoy the prospect of living dangerously and with regular intervals of fear and loathing you would use the following line in your pg_hba.conf file,  although I seriously council against it.

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
```

This basically says "Anybody from anywhere can access my Postgresql server" I have provided it simply as an example of how careful you have to be.

[The documentation for the current version of Postgresql 9.6 can be found here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) Previous versions are also available near that link but in the case of pg_hba.conf things do not appear to have changed between versions.

Comment: This post should maybe updated to the new auth method scram-sha-256  that replaces the md5 one.