# Is it possible my friend's pc to acces to my database in PostgreSQL through my program?

Tags: database, psql

i have a question. Is it possible to make my friend and other people access to a database in PostgreSQL to write in tables? If yes, how can i do that?

I'm connecting to my database through this string:

```
db = psycopg2.connect(
    host = "192.168.1.xxx",
    user = "Ripetra",
    password = "MyPassword",
    database = "Ripetra",
    )
etc...
```

any answer will be appreciated <3

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you develop a good understanding of the security risks involved here before going forward with opening your database to the internet. If you do not know what you are doing, this is very dangerous.

Googling for "postgresql allow remote connections", it is important that you understand what you're doing before following these steps. [this stackoverflow answer might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378278/allow-access-to-postgresql-from-any-computer). (this question is a duplicate of that question, please put more effort in avoiding duplicate questions, generalizing your question in your search query usually helps. Go from my friend needs to access postgresql -> allow public access to postgresql.)

[another stackoverflow question that might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080307/access-postgresql-server-from-lan)

[Some more about it here.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44136/having-a-postgresql-database-exposed-to-the-internet)

You're likely on a home connection, in that case, you will need to become familiar with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding